# Jquery - Form not being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have some code which, when the search box is clicked, geocodes a location (unless laready done by the autosuggest) in the location box and should the submit the form.

The problem is, the form does not get submitted after the searhc button is clicked and the geocode is successful. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

This is a link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/35/

This is the full code:

```
$(function () { 

    var input = $("#loc"),
        lat = $("#lat"),
        lng = $("#lng"),
        lastQuery = null,
        autocomplete;

    function processLocation(query) {
        var query = $.trim(input.val()),
            geocoder;

        if (!query || query == lastQuery) {
            console.log("Empty or same variable");
            return;
        }

        lastQuery = query;

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            address: query
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            } else {
                alert("We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
            }
        });
    }

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
        types: ["geocode"],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "uk"
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

    $('#searchform').on('submit', function (event) {
        processLocation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` could be the problem

Comment: I think so too, but I need that to stop the form being submitted without the location first beign geocoded :s

Comment: Could you not run processLocation() on the change event of the text fields and have the submit button disabled until the values are valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `processLocation(query)` expects for `query`, but idea would be this:
*1. change function signature*

```
function processLocation(query, doSubmit) { // <--- new parameter
    var query = $.trim(input.val()),
        geocoder;

    if (!query || query == lastQuery) {
        console.log("Empty or same variable");
        return;
    }

    lastQuery = query;

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        address: query
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            if (doSubmit){
                 $('#searchform').submit(); //<-- new param usage
            }
        } else {
            alert("We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
        }
    });
}
```

*2. remove this call*

```
$('#searchform').on('submit', function (event) {
    alert('Submitted')
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

*3. add this call*

```
$('#search').click(function(){
     processLocation(new Date(), true); //<-- don't know what's the first param
});
```

Tried to play around  in your jsfiddle but had no success as I was constantly getting `Empty or same variable` message into console. I think you know your logic better and you'll figure out

Answer (score 0):

I would just have the submit button disabled until the values are valid?

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search" disabled="disabled">

search.removeAttr('disabled')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/38/

?

Comment: Hi Stefan, something like this might work but from a usability point of view it isn't so great, especially since it isnt a required field.