# Jquery Stop Submit if two fields empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am new to jquery and javascript but I wondered if anyone had any nice ideas about how I can show the user an error (alert) if they try to submit the form when both fields are empty.

Here is the code I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/uaZkV/1/

I believe the relevant bit of the code is here:

```
$('#searchform').on('submit', function (event) {
    var form = this;

    event.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

    processLocation(function (success) {
        if (success) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
            form.submit()
        }
    });
```

In sudo code I'm after something like this:

```
If #kw & #loc == 0 
    then alert "Cannot leave fields blank"
```

Comment: `if( $(this).find('.class-of-input1').val() == '' )`

Comment: you asked almost the exact same question a few days ago!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583453/jquery-form-not-being-submitted/16583813#16583813

Comment: To be fair, that was a different question and the answers to that do not answer this question

Comment: If I understood you right my answer should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the IDs of the input fields are: 
`kw` , `loc` and when I say 'ID' I mean:

```
<input type='text' name='bla' id='kw'>
<input type='text' name='bla' id='loc'>
```

You can do this:

```
if( $('#kw').val() == '' && $('#loc').val() == '')
{
 alert("Cannot leave fields blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way to validate your form would be JQuery validation plugin

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Anyway, you should not stop submiting because there is an error. First you validate and if there is no error you submit

Comment: "First you validate and if there is no error you submit" - isn't that what his snippet does?

Comment: He stops the automatic submission from the button click, then he validates, then he submits if the validation succeeds if there is no error in the callback from `processLocation`.

Comment: sure but why letting submitting if you stop the submit behind ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this feels like using a hammer to open a peanut

Comment: use the plugin... it is a nice way to validate on client-side otherwise on your submit button you call your own function that validate and return false or true..it is just that... simple